# How does "fighting" work?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-time

In the movie *In Time*, we hear several references to fighting, it's implied that this is some sort of fight for time rather than a physical brawl.

Later in the film we see Will and the Minuteman "fighting". It looks to be some kind of arm wrestle (with their clock free arms)... what exactly is going on and how is time/money transferred?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen throughout the movie, time can be given from one person to another, and it can be taken by force as well.  Fighting is done in an arm-wrestling style position, where each person holds the other person's hand.  It's then a contest of wills to pull as much time from the other person while not letting their time get pulled as well.

Comment: So they can somehow conciously control the transferral from one person to the other (haven't seen the movie for some time, though)?

Comment: We know it can be stolen from unconscious people, so I guess a fight is just a two-way steal.

Answer (score 1):

The people work and earn time rather than money. That clock ticks. In the movie when they wrestle they transfer time from one to  other. If one person's losing, their time is transferred to the opponent. That way they fight and win and lose - until death in that scene.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout the movie, transfer speed and direction seems to be determined by the relative vertical positions of the clocks. They're fighting for the top position.

I'm seeing the same basic answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11027/in-the-movie-in-time-how-would-the-transferring-of-time-work%20*here*)

Comment: Add relevant information in answer